# Base_Image is not definied in loop (for)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have this code, who insert a image into the canvas:

```
 function image(){

base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = '0.png';
base_image.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(base_image,243,68,24,24);
}

}
```

But I want to automate this code, and I put in this format

```
function image(){

for(q=0;q<6;q++){

base_image[q] = new Image();
base_image.src[q] = q + '.png';
base_image[q].onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(base_image[0],243,68,24,24);
ctx.drawImage(base_image[1],478,48,24,24);
ctx.drawImage(base_image[2],113,477,24,24);
ctx.drawImage(base_image[3],445,144,24,24);
ctx.drawImage(base_image[4],789,220,24,24);
}

}

}
```

And the console give this messange

> ```
> Base_Image is not definied
> ```

So, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few fixes:

- declare base_image as an array
- base_image.src[q] should be base_image[q].src
- you need to be sure all images are loaded before trying to draw them.
- you have 0.png,...,5.png images loading by you're only drawImage for 0-4.

Good luck with your project!

Here's example code:

```
function image(){

    var base_image=[];
    var loaded=0;

    for(q=0;q<6;q++){
        base_image[q] = new Image();
        base_image[q].onload = function(){
            if(++loaded==6){
                ctx.drawImage(base_image[0],243,68,24,24);
                ctx.drawImage(base_image[1],478,48,24,24);
                ctx.drawImage(base_image[2],113,477,24,24);
                ctx.drawImage(base_image[3],445,144,24,24);
                ctx.drawImage(base_image[4],789,220,24,24);
            }

        }
        base_image[q].src ="house16x16.png"; // q + '.png';

    }

}
```